# The substitute for <pre> tag?

Tags: html, pre

I am looking for a substitute for the HTML `<pre>` tag. Using the `<pre>` tag, long lines sometimes have issues on different resolutions, and it just gets worse and worse. The problem is I need to use the `<pre>` tag because the one who will be the updater of the website doesn't know much HTML and also doesn't have the time. So it would be easiest for him to simply copy and paste the text. But while using the `<pre>` tag makes that easier, it causes other complications down the line, making other things harder and harder. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like Markdown or Textile on the server to generate HTML from a simplified markup language.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want a substitute?  If the `<pre>` does what you want, use it.  But I agree with you, using `<pre>` is not going to look good.

David has a good suggestion.  Try a search on "convert text to html."  If you need a WYSIWYG editor for a CMS that you are building, search for "wysiwyg html editor."  [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) is popular, also [YUI 2: Rich Text Editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/)